# python Popen hangs

Tags: python, freeze, popen

I use Popen to open tclsh, and try to run `puts aaaaaaaaaaa...` command(aaa... is very long) by sending command through PIPE

It works fine, but, when I run the command twice (aaaa... need long enough), and I read stdout by PIPE, the code will hang

I tried to enlarge default bufsize, however it doesn't work

what's going on under the hook? anyone can help?

```
proc = Popen(
    ['C:\\Tcl\\bin\\tclsh.exe'],
    stdin=PIPE,
    stdout=PIPE,
    stderr=PIPE
)

proc.stdin.write(bytearray('puts ' + 'a' * 100000 + 'ends\n', 'utf-8'))
proc.stdin.write(bytearray('puts ' + 'a' * 100000 + 'ends\n', 'utf-8'))
proc.stdin.flush()

stdout = b''
while proc.poll() == None:
    if stdout.endswith(b'ends'):
        break
    else:
        stdout += proc.stdout.read1(1)

print(stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

---

finally, i use tempfile instead PIPE in stdout

```
    self._tempfile = tempfile.mktemp()
    self._tempfile_in = open(self._tempfile, 'wb')
    self._tempfile_out = open(self._tempfile, 'rb')

    self._process = subprocess.Popen(
        [self.tcl_exe] + list(self.tcl_exe_args),
        stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout = self._tempfile_in,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

......

```
    self._tempfile_out.read1(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The pipe buffers are not infinitely large.  You filled the stdin buffer, then tclsh filled its stdout buffer, and it can't move forward to read the next line until YOU pull something from stdout.  So, you're blocked in the second write.

Comment: Maybe also mention that the `subprocess` documentation explicitly warns about this. ***"Note** This will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use `Popen.communicate()` when using pipes to avoid that."*

Comment: how to enlarge PIPE in the windows when using PIPE? or how to figure out the PIPE size. I have tried by test, it seems 4096. is there a way to find out the PIPE size, and change the PIPE size?

Comment: I tried communicate(), it does work,  however, I need run many scripts  in the single tclsh, so I have used file instead pipe to fix it